# Android: Write text to txt

Tags: android, file, text, fileoutputstream

With the following code, I try to write to my sdcard:

```
public void writedata(String data) {
          //BufferedWriter out = null;

          System.out.println(data);
          try{

              FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("/sdcard/tsxt.txt"));
              out.write(data.getBytes());
              out.close();  

                } catch (Exception e) { //fehlende Permission oder sd an pc gemountet}
                    System.out.println("CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCALSKDJLAK");
                }

          }
```

The permission in the Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

But now, when I open the file, nothing is in there. Where´s the problem? I´m sure `data` has some value.

**EDIT:**

I get this message in the LogCat:

```
02-06 01:59:51.676: W/System.err(1197): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard0/sdcard/tsxt.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I tried to create the file on the sdcard but still the same error. Is there a code that the File is created if it doesn´t exists?

Comment: Do you have this in your manifest? 
<uses-permission a ndroid:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: A `BufferedWriter` would be more appropriate to write text. (http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-bufferedwriter-example/)

Comment: Also the solution with a BufferedWriter doesn´t work!

Comment: you shouldn't hard-code the path to your external storage (SDCard). use `getExternalStorageDirectory()`

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with this code:

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/dir");

File file = new File(dir, "tsxt.txt");

FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

So the path to the file is not correct. You should remove directory name:

```
File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/");
```

Comment: I get this message in LogCat: 
02-06 01:59:51.676: W/System.err(1197): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard0/sdcard/tsxt.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
BufferedWriter out;         
try {

FileWriter fileWriter= new FileWriter(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/tsxt.txt")

out = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

out.write("Your text to write");

out.close(); 

}catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}catch (IOException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is still the same issue. The file is empty(I´ve created it before)

Comment: still getting java.io.FileNotFoundException?

Comment: Just wondering, have you mounted your device storage or connected it with the pc in Mass Storage Mode?

Answer (score 1):

```
  try{
    File myFile = new File("/sdcard/tsxt.txt");
    myFile.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
    OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
    myOutWriter.append("your data here");
    myOutWriter.close();
    fOut.close();
}catch(Exception e){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 FileOutputStream fOut =openFileOutput(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/tsxt.txt",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
 OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
//---write the string to the file---
 osw.write(str);
 osw.flush();
 osw.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Before writing any file on sd card you need to check that is sdcard mounted or not, if not then just mount it and then write the file on it using external storage path.

you may use following code to check is sdcard mount or not

```
static public boolean hasStorage(boolean requireWriteAccess) {
    //TODO: After fix the bug,  add "if (VERBOSE)" before logging errors.
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    Log.v(TAG, "storage state is " + state);

    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        if (requireWriteAccess) {
            boolean writable = checkFsWritable();
            Log.v(TAG, "storage writable is " + writable);
            return writable;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else if (!requireWriteAccess && Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

if(hasStorage(true)){

//call here your writedata() function



}
```

Answer (score 0):

This Code is working perfectly..

```
public File getAlbumStorageDir(String albumName) {
        // Get the directory for the user's public pictures directory.
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/files", albumName);
       Log.d("File", "Bug file Created" + file.getAbsolutePath());
        return file;
    }`
```

To write the textfile inside sd Card(/storage/sdcard0/files/bugReport.txt)

```
 try{
             outputStream = new FileOutputStream(this.getAlbumStorageDir(bugReport.txt));
             outputStream.write(report.toString().getBytes());
             Log.d("File","Report Generated");
             outputStream.close();
         }
         catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
```