# Android Room - Select All then write to text file

Tags: android, database, select, android-room

I followed the [Android Room with a View tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#0) and I was successfully able to recreate the tutorial app. All of my code can be found in that tutorial. The only difference with my app now is my MainActivity is a webView and then when the user clicks on a button in the toolbar, they're taken to the Room with a View app functionality exactly how it is in the tutorial. So essentially I just added another activity beforehand.

I've tried using the methods getAllWords() and getAlphabetizedWords() associated with LiveData and dumped the results into the Logcat, but they always come out in a hash-like string (Ex: Word@6f2f356). I'm trying to get the exact value of the word I'm pulling from the Room database.

I have 2 issues currently:

1. I'd like to select all of the words in the Room database table from the MainActivity.
2. After selecting all terms from the table, I'd like to write them all to a text file or CSV.

In my MainActivity I'm using the function below to send the user to the start of the Room with a View tutorial functionality (WordList). My WordList class is the equivalent to the tutorial's MainActivity. Within this WordList class, I've tried using getAllWords() and it returns the terms in a hash-like state.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.nix_menu_back:
            onBackPressed();
            break;
        case R.id.nix_menu_forward:
            onForwardPressed();
            break;
        case R.id.nix_menu_refresh:
            nixWebView.reload();
            break;
        case R.id.nix_string_list:
            nixWebView.reload();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, WordList.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Can someone please explain to me how to select all terms in the Room database and output them in a readable format to Logcat and an internal text file?

Any help is appreciated, and my sincerest apologies if this is a repeat! I've checked around SO and the only question I found related to my situation didn't cover this situation.

I'm happy to provide more code if asked. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Hashy looking strings

If you want your `Word` object to be printed in a readable object you should override the method `public String toString()` for that class since the default implementation returns that hashy looking `String`.

Some light on this could be:

```
public class Word {
    // Other stuff you may have
    @Override
    public String toString() {
         return this.wordID+" - "this.wordContent;
    }
}
```

And this could print: "12 - Cat"

#### To list all words.

The methods provided in that codelab are enough to list all the words contained in the SQLite DB.

#### To save them in an external file as plain text.

Check [this other stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983506/android-write-text-to-txt)

Don't forget to add 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` file!

Comment: Awesome! I'll be able to implement this in a few hours! Thank you so much, I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Please do! And let me know if you need something else!

Comment: Looks like I got a chance to look at this sooner than expected! I'm a bit of an Android newbie so please excuse my ignorance lol. So is this as simple as initializing a new Word class instance in my MainActivity, calling getWord() and calling toString()? I don't understand why I can't declare a database object in my MainActivity and just query the data.

Comment: I'm also open to sharing my simple project, if applicable. :/

Comment: What kind of error are you getting and what do you exactly mean?

Comment: Check this gist to see some usage of this new implementation:

https://gist.github.com/NanoSpicer/4cdca5edab28b2a4e00bafb292195f09

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190051/discussion-between-some-random-it-boy-and-breezy).